# Ubuntu 12.04 freezes during install on Compaq Presario V2000

Tags: 12.04, installation, compaq, presario

I am trying to upgrade an older Compaq Presario V2000 from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04.  I had no problems installing 10.04, but I'm having some issues with the 12.04 install freezing.  I downloaded the file from the website and made a bootable CD.  When I boot up the computer to start the install, it shows the Ubuntu logo and then eventually freezes on the logo.  I re-downloaded the file again and made a startup disk with a USB jump drive instead. It also freezes on boot up of the 12.04 installation in the same spot.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you stuck in purple screen showing five dots below ubuntu logo? press `Esc` and see the logs where it is stuck

Comment: After reboot following system update, the LED on the 5-in-1 reader was flashing every second, and these messages were appearing in /var/log/syslog: Feb 28 12:49:42 ac6sl07 kernel: [2499630.568088] tifm_core: MMC/SD card detected in socket 0:3
Feb 28 12:49:42 ac6sl07 kernel: [2499630.692103] tifm_sd0:3 : card not ready - probe failed on initialization
Feb 28 12:49:42 ac6sl07 kernel: [2499631.345639] tifm0 : demand removing card from socket 0:3 After some investigation, I found that this command stopped the bad behavior: sudo modprobe -r tifm_ms I then added an additional entry to the blacklist

Answer (score 1):

I found it necessary to add the following boot parameters:

```
sdhci.blacklist=yes sdhci_pci.blacklist=yes mmc0.blacklist=yes mmc_core.blacklist=yes b43.blacklist=yes
```

That is, power on, after BIOS prompt disappears, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, in the GRUB menu hit <kbd>e</kbd>, add the above boot parameters in place of `quiet splash`, and hit <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Once the system comes up, add `blacklist sdhci`, etc. at end of `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and then execute `sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-initramfs -u`.

**Source:** http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2009830 ([this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12052763&postcount=2))

To make wifi work, see [this community documentation wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20Internet%20access).

Answer (score 0):

Since the traditional installations don't work. I will suggest that you try to install Ubuntu from an alternate iso. Also called text based installation.  I don't know if is gonna work but hopefully it will. Here is the link of Ubuntu recommending the installation to people having problems with the graphical interface installation. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads .Here is the link where you can read more about the alternate iso and download it. http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ Hope it helps you.