# What to do if system stops running during install?

Tags: system-installation

My system is an IBM thinkpad T23 I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 and the computer stops running during "configuring bcmwl-Kernel-source". What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your computer is always connected to power, when performing updates or installing systems. Doing CPU heavy stuff, while on battery will drain the battery in no-time.

If the PC dying on you is not the case, then please be more specific in your question. Like explaining exactly what you mean by "stops running".

Answer (score 0):

Just wait... The system is working in background and unless you see more than 2 hours and it do not advance, you can stop the installation and start again from scratch. Remember that doing so you will leave your system unbootable.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with some broadcom wireless device. I had a similar problem with a compaq presario v2000. What you need to do is to blacklist this device on startup. What you need to do is to get in the grub menu on startup. Normally, you should get there by holding [shift] on startup.

One you get to the menu, you press the key [e]

Then replace quiet splash by b43.blacklist=yes

Then, type [f10]

Now, your system should work, but the wireless will be disable. It is very important to NOT install the STA driver proposed by Ubuntu proprietary drivers.

Here is where I found the information:

[Ubuntu 12.04 freezes during install on Compaq Presario V2000](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156718/ubuntu-12-04-freezes-during-install-on-compaq-presario-v2000)